# compiler migration(5 to 6.19) warnings in c, diag_suppress 170

Tags: c

Due to compiler migration the diag_suppress is not supported anymore in arm compiler 6v, hence need suggestion how to replace this:

```c
#pragma diag_suppress 170
```

What is 170 how to replace the same?

```
warning: '#pragma diag_suppress' is an Arm Compiler 5 extension, and is not supported by Arm Compiler for Embedded 6 [-Warmcc-pragma-diag]
```

For another warning replaced `#pragma diag_suppress 550` with `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"`.

Comment: And *what* compiler are you using? Have you read the documentation for the compiler, about the `diag_suppress` pragma? What does the documentation tell you?

Comment: Apart from the pragma warning, what other warnings/errors do you get with the new compiler which you did not get with the previous one? They are likely to be the target.

Comment: As for supressing warnings, that's seldom a good idea. Usually it's a rather *bad* idea. It's much better to fix the actual root cause of the warning instead. For example, if you get warnings about unused variables, perhaps you should take some time to think about why you have the variable to begin with?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That depends upon the compiler, reason for the warning, and whether there are any ways of telling the compiler that a construct is correct.  For example, if one wants to store the largest possible value to a structure member of some unsigned type, the syntax "-1" will work regardless of the type of the field, and continue to work even if the type of the field changes to something bigger.  By contrast, if one uses `(uint16_t)(-1)` and the field type is changed to `uint32`, the code would no longer be correct but wouldn't generate a diagnostic.